# Group associated with this curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, algebraic-curves, elliptic-curves

Consider an Elliptic curve with a singularity (double point) over $\mathbb{F}_p$ $$y^2=x^2(x-a) $$ where $a$ is a quadratic residue in ${\mathbb{F}_p}^*$.

We can easily count the number of (non-singular)points on this curve over ${\mathbb{F}_p}$ (They are $p-1$). Also it is well known that $$E_{ns}({\mathbb{F}_p}) \cong {\mathbb{F}_p}^* $$

Now consider an exact analogous condition, Now my curve is  $$ y^3=x^3(x-a) $$ over ${\mathbb{F}_p}$ such that  $3|p-1$ . The nonsingular points on this curve is again $p-1$.

**My question is** does the group associated with this curve (Picard group or Jacobian variety) known ? My guess would be $\oplus_{i=1}^{k}{\mathbb{F}_p}^*$

Comment: What is denoted by $k$?

Comment: k is some integer ! it might be related to the genus of this curve. I just want to say the form of my picard group would be like this !

Comment: Are you looking at the affine curve or its projective completion? The curves you have are rational and the answer  to your question can be found in Milnor's book on K-theory, using conductors.

Comment: @Mohan I am looking for Affine solutions.

Comment: @Mohan I don't know K-theory, So a bit of details (page number, basic ideas) would be of great help.

Comment: keyword: generalized jacobians; look for Isabelle Dechenes' thesis.